# Pyspark: failing due to OutOfMemory on window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a working solution when using a small dataset but fails on very large one (> 100mio records) due to OutOfMemory. I am new to spark so am not sure how to debug or where to look.
I am aggregating over a 30min window on various ports

```
# TCP ports
ports = ['22', '25', '53', '80', '88', '123', '514', '443', '8080', '8443']


def add_port_column(r_df, port, window):
    '''
    Input:
        r_df: dataframe
        port: port
        window: pyspark window to be used

    Output: pyspark dataframe
    '''

    return r_df.withColumn('pkts_src_port_{}_30m'.format(port), F.when(F.col('source_port') == port, F.sum('source_packets').over(window)).otherwise(0))\
        .withColumn('pkts_dst_port_{}_30m'.format(port), F.when(F.col('destination_port') == port, F.sum('destination_packets').over(window)).otherwise(0))

w = (Window()
     .partitionBy("source_ip")
     .orderBy(F.col("timestamp"))
     .rangeBetween(-window_time, 0))

flows_filtered_v3_df = (reduce(partial(add_port_column,window=w_s),
    ports,
    flows_filtered_v3_df
))
```

Not sure this is the exact error but read a lot of OOMs

```
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2111)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2060)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2049)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:740)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2081)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.read(SnappyInputStream.java:167)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.io.ReadAheadInputStream$1.run(ReadAheadInputStream.java:168)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - 20/09/04 17:39:38 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - 20/09/04 17:39:38 ERROR util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[read-ahead,5,main]
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.hasNextChunk(SnappyInputStream.java:422)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.read(SnappyInputStream.java:167)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:557)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at com.dataiku.dip.spark.ParquetWriter$.saveParquetDataset(ParquetWriter.scala:63)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at com.dataiku.dip.spark.StdDataikuSparkContext.saveHDFSableWithFastPathIfPossible(StdDataikuSparkContext.scala:984)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at com.dataiku.dip.spark.StdDataikuSparkContext.internalSave(StdDataikuSparkContext.scala:897)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at com.dataiku.dss.spark.DataikuSparkContext$class.save(DataikuSparkContext.scala:83)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.io.ReadAheadInputStream$1.run(ReadAheadInputStream.java:168)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at com.dataiku.dip.spark.StdDataikuSparkContext.save(StdDataikuSparkContext.scala:60)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at com.dataiku.dip.spark.StdDataikuSparkContext.savePyDataFrame(StdDataikuSparkContext.scala:673)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[17:39:40] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Spark submit

```
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --conf spark.executor.memory=8g --conf spark.local.dir=/pkgs/cdh/tmp/spark --conf spark.yarn.security.tokens.hive.enabled=false --conf spark.yarn.security.credentials.hadoopfs.enabled=false --conf spark.security.credentials.hive.enabled=false --conf spark.app.name=DSS (Py): compute_flows_window_pyspark_2020-04-14 --conf spark.io.compression.codec=snappy --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=80 --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=false --conf spark.shuffle.compress=false --conf spark.dku.limitedLogs={"filePartitioner.noMatch":100,"s3.ignoredPath":100,"s3.ignoredFile":100} --conf spark.security.credentials.hadoopfs.enabled=false --conf spark.jars.repositories=https://nexus.bisinfo.org:8443/repository/maven-central --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=600
```

EDIT:
After incresing memory it is complaining about

```
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:257)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1408)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - Caused by: java.io.IOException: PARSING_ERROR(2)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.throw_error(SnappyNative.java:98)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.uncompressedLength(Native Method)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompressedLength(Snappy.java:634)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.hasNextChunk(SnappyInputStream.java:435)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.read(SnappyInputStream.java:167)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    at org.apache.spark.io.ReadAheadInputStream$1.run(ReadAheadInputStream.java:168)
[09:20:10] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `df.groupBy("source_ip").agg(count("*")).show()`? It's possible that there could be too many `source_ip` for the memory assigned.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski The ip with the highest count has a value of 267'639'084. There are 2453 grouped IPs.

Comment: How do you submit the app for execution? I'm particularly interested in memory settings, but other options may be of help too.

Comment: I specifically set ```spark.executor.memory=8g``` as well as ```spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=80``` ```spark.shuffle.compress=false``` and ```spark.shuffle.spill.compress``` but this is more a trial and error

Comment: How do you `spark-submit` the app?

Comment: I edited my question if that is the information you are looking for. I truncated the -jar options and all of that. The spark job is executed through Dataiku.

Comment: Have you tried `--spark.driver.memory=8g`? Commands are executed on the driver (most of the time).

Comment: It seems to go furher now but complaining about snappy compression (edited my question with the error) and eventually fail. I also have the feeling it is highly ineffective with this window implementation I have especially if I have over 30 features that require window functionality.